# ifconfig fails because usb ethernet adapter is not ready yet on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I have an ethernet adapter connected via USB-C and its configuration in my `/etc/rc.conf`.
On system startup the configuration fails because the usb stack is loaded *after* the configuration is initiated and therefor the device does not exist yet.

Is there a way to adjust the startup order or another mechanism to fix this?

Comment: What init system does FreeBSD use?

Answer (score 1):

The USB NIC seems to take a finite time to become available, which sometimes occurs after the "netif" service is started. This results in missing network interfaces and a broken server.

One solution is to insert a short time delay before the "netif" service is started which gives more time for the NIC to become available. This can be accomplished by adding a simple RC script.

For example, add a file called `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/ourdelay`, which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

# PROVIDE: ourdelay
# REQUIRE: FILESYSTEMS
# BEFORE:  netif
# KEYWORD: nojail

. /etc/rc.subr

name="ourdelay"

rcvar="${name}_enable"
start_cmd="${name}_start"
stop_cmd=":"

: ${ourdelay_enable:="NO"}
: ${ourdelay_time:="5"}

ourdelay_start()
{
    echo "Begin delay of ${ourdelay_time} seconds"
    sleep ${ourdelay_time}
    echo "Finish delay of ${ourdelay_time} seconds"
}

load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

This file will need the execute bit set, use the command:

```
# chmod 555 /usr/local/etc/rc.d/ourdelay
```

Then enable it in your `/etc/rc.conf` or `/etc/rc.conf.local` file, using:

```
ourdelay_enable="YES"
```

Comment: I was pointed to netwait. Seems to be exactly what I was looking for. See: https://reviews.freebsd.org/D4608 and https://blog.danielisz.org/2019/07/20/netwait/

Comment: You should post that as an answer for the next person that encounters this problem.

Comment: I have not tried it yet. Planned to post as an answer once I tried it :)

Comment: So I got to try out the netwait thing I posted but so far I could not get it working. Seems the device comes up/down a couple of times and not sure that's the reason